# How to add multiline option on RegularExpression attribute?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am using:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(""|\[)?[a-zA-Z0-9']{1,125}(""|\])?$")]
```

to make sure each line of a multiline textbox is properly matched. I cannot however figure out how to add the global flag and multline flag options. Is it impossible with MVC? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the [`RegularExpressionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) supports passing options, so here's one that allows it (compile checked but not tested):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, 
                         AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RegExAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string Pattern { get; set; }
    public RegexOptions Options { get; set; }

    public RegExAttribute(string pattern) : this(pattern, RegexOptions.None) { }
    public RegExAttribute(string pattern, RegexOptions options)
    {
        Pattern = pattern;
        Options = options;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), Pattern, Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I created one based off that.

Answer (score 5):

[You can add an inline option to enable MultiLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx) without having to add a RegexOptions overload to the Attribute. That also ensures the expression will work in Javascript as well.

```
    [RegularExpression(@"(?m)^(""|\[)?[a-zA-Z0-9']{1,125}(""|\])?$")]
```

Comment: it looks like you are correct... :( http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would do it with Regex, basically not relying on multiline flag or attribute, instead you explicitly define the regex to allow new lines but the same pattern needs to follow

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(""|\[)?[a-zA-Z0-9']{1,125}(""|\])?(?:\r?\n(""|\[)?[a-zA-Z0-9']{1,125}(""|\])?)*$")]
```