# Regular Expressions New line issue

Tags: regex

I'm using below regular expression to validate text area NOT to have any URLs.

```
"@"(?!.*?(https?://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_.,\s-]+)\.([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?)*"
```

I have tried and tested this expression on a single line, and it worked, but on multiline text area it fails when hitting enter (new line)

Comment: Have you tried the m flag?

Comment: @Avinash Rah it's C# MVC application

Comment: @Zach No i haven't tried the m flag.

Comment: This might help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you're using C#, but didn't mention how you're using the regex. I'm assuming you're just doing simple validation for the existence of a link within the string.

If you do a simple `Regex.IsMatch()` or `Regex.Matches()`, then it will search across the new line boundaries. If you provide which function you're using it'd make it easier to explain why your version is not working, but there's a few functions that will only search for the first match and stop. ie. `Regex.Match()`

Most people start looking at the `RegexOptions.Singleline` or `RegexOptions.Multiline`. These will change the behavior of your regex, but it's probably not what you're after. `Singleline` changes the dot (`.`) so that it will match new line characters, and `Multiline` allows the anchor tags `^$` to match each individual line instead of the entire string.

So for instance you can do this:

```
var regex = @"(?!.*?(https?://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_.,\s-]+)\.([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?)*";

var str = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Integer vitae enim nibh. Nam mi ligula, congue sit amet http://www.google.com
            viverra ut, egestas id tortor. Sed ac ex sollicitudin, viverra eros nec, 
            malesuada nibh. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in dui tincidunt, non consectetur mi vulputate. 
            Etiam massa purus, mollis vitae suscipit ut, lobortis sed lectus. Sed egestas ligula sed velit ullamcorper pretium. Etiam lacinia ex dapibus imperdiet elementum. 
            Nam dapibus nibh ante, quis malesuada erat euismod quis. Duis interdum id nisi nec iaculis.";

if (Regex.IsMatch(str, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    //The string contains a link
}
```

Now the other thing you might consider is simplifying you're regex a bit. If you're just validating that the text does not contain a link, then there isn't really a reason to match on the surrounding text. So I'd personally remove the negative look around and simplify the regex a little.

```
(?:https?://)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.,\s-]+)\.(?:[a-z.]{2,6})(?:[/\w .-]*)*/?
```

This will not work if you're doing some type of text manipulation based on the link, but for simple validation it'll work fine.

**EDIT**

For the MVC attribute `RegularExpressionAttribute` to work you'll need to use the following regex.

```
^(?!.*?(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+)\.([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?)(?:[\r\n]|.)*$
```

The issue here is there's not an easy way to pass the regex option for `Singleline` mode. Another cleaner solution would be to extend the Attribute class and create your own validator. Similar to what a use suggested on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689603/how-to-add-multiline-option-on-regularexpression-attribute).

Below is the code piece from the other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689603/how-to-add-multiline-option-on-regularexpression-attribute) showing how to create a validator to allow for the regex options.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, 
                         AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RegExAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string Pattern { get; set; }
    public RegexOptions Options { get; set; }

    public RegExAttribute(string pattern) : this(pattern, RegexOptions.None) { }
    public RegExAttribute(string pattern, RegexOptions options)
    {
        Pattern = pattern;
        Options = options;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), Pattern, Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using MVC Data Annotation [RegularExpression("REGEXP","ERROR")]

Comment: Im using this regular expression @"^(?!.*?(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+)\.([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?).*$"; as mentioned,it works good on single line, but whenever i hit enter the reg exp fails.

Comment: @Nusir: Try this one `@"^(?!.*?(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+)\.([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?)(?:[\r\n]|.)*$"`. From what I can tell you can't override the RegexOptions, but what you need is `RegexOptions.Singleline` to be enabled.