# Overriding RegularExpressionAttribute.IsValid in Nuget System.ComponentModel.Annotations

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-core

I'm using the Nuget package [System.ComponentModel.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/) for data validation. Now I'd like to add validation through Regular Expressions too. The problem is that I'd like to add `RegexOptions` sort of like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689603/how-to-add-multiline-option-on-regularexpression-attribute). The nuget package version of `RegularExpressionAttribute.IsValid()` doesn't return a `bool` like the .NET Framework DLL does, instead it returns a `ValidationResult` which doesn't seem to have an as straight forward approach for overriding as I can't find any way of altering the result of the validation. The reason why I'm using the Nuget package instead of the Framework provided version is that it needs to support both .NET 4.5 and .NET Standard 1.1 which the Nuget package supports. So how do I override `RegularExpressionAttribute.IsValid()` in any meaningful way?

Comment: From what I understand the .NET Standard and .NET Framework versions are incompatible. This was the reason I chose the Nuget package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by referencing .NETStandard 1.3 instead of .NETStandard 1.1 as that version adds an override for `RegularExpressionAttribute.IsValid()` that returns a `bool` in addition to the one that returns a `ValidationResult`. But since .NET Framework 4.5 only implements .NETStandard 1.1 I had to target multiple frameworks resulting in an edit to `project.csproj` ending up looking like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.3;net45</TargetFrameworks>
    <RootNamespace>Foobar</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Foobar</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="4.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```